# How to change the font size of the image caption for different images?

Tags: fonts, graphics, captions, fontsize, size

I am searching for a way to adjust the size of the caption.

All the solution I have found deals with the caption package and uses something that changes the size globally.

I wish to adjust each of them differently.

For example, in the following image, I would like to keep shrimp as it is, dolphin a little bit bigger, and whale the largest. Is it possible?

Perhaps something like: change caption size globally, reset, change again, reset, change again, reset.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{shrimp}
    \caption{shrimp}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Dolphin}
    \caption{dolphin}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{whale}
    \caption{whale}
\end{figure}


% or play with the following

 \begin{figure}
    \caption{shrimp}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm,width=6cm]{shrimp} 
    \hfill
    \caption{dolphin}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm,width=6cm]{Dolphin}
    \hfill
    \caption{whale}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm,width=6cm]{whale}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the `caption` package to your preamble, and then just write like this

```
\caption*{\large Figure 2: FigName}
\caption*{\Huge Figure 3: Blah Blah}
```

See full code [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zcpnqcmgjyrr).

You can also customize the font size to whatever you want by the `\fontsize` command.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `caption` package local changes are possible, too, e.g.:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{Dolphin}
    \captionsetup{size=large}
    \caption{dolphin}
\end{figure}
```

This way the `\captionsetup{size=large}` only affects captions in this particular `figure`.

See also `caption` package documentation, section 1 "Using this package":

> It’s good to know that \captionsetup has an effect on the current environment only.
>   So if you want to change settings for the current figure or table only, just place the
>   \captionsetup command inside the figure or table right before the \caption
>   command.